# How does a javascript circular reference work?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why this works.

```
var a = {};
a.hello = a;
```

If you explore the object in the console you'll see something like this:
[image]

`a.hello = a` is a circular reference. It seems that when we assign `a.hello = a` everything would blow up. Can someone explain what is happening internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with objects JavaScript handles them by reference, not as copy. So circular constructs are no problem.

Answer (score 5):

You have a single object.

That object contains a property, which is a pointer to the same object.

That's all.

From there, you can continually recurse into `a.hello.hello.hello.hello` as much as you like, but you're still just referencing the same object. That is, `a.hello === a.hello.hello` for any depths.

Given that `window` behaves in the same way (`window.window.window.window.MUSHROOM`) it's a good thing it doesn't "blow up"!